# Save and Retrieve an Image c# WPF Sql

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf

I'm new here and I've also searched about my problem, but I could manage to solve it.
**I would like to save and retrieve images to/from Database(SQL) in C# WPF.**
I have to make a project about storing a recipe. A recipe contains a table in the **Database with the columns: Id, Name, Image**, **Content**.The Information has to be saved and then **the name** of the recipe(currently done) **and images**(*here is the problem*) has to be displayed **in a Grid**, (so far i don't need to work with the "content" column from the database. That comes later). 
I think that I have succeeded in the saving of image to the database, but I am not completely sure. **If the saving of the image to the DB is correct, I need a function to retrieve it.**

I would be happy for some help. Many Thanks!
D.Tsvet

[Thats a sample of the future end result. The image has to be under the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7hD0.png)

```
// Add recipe Window

DataSet ds;
string strName, imageName;
byte[] data;
string FileName;

public partial class add_Recipe : Window    
{

      DataSet ds;
      string strName, imageName;
      byte[] data;
      string FileName;

      public add_Recipe()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
      // Upload a picture from your device
      private void browseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

          OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
          op.Title = "Select a picture";
          op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
            "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
            "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
          if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
          {
              FileName = op.FileName.ToString();
              image_box.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
}

string dbConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\guiProjekte\Stands\Projekt_GUI_200418\Projekt_GUI_20042018\Projekt_GUI_160418\Projekt_GUI\1234\1234\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;";

      private void saveRecipe_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

          FileStream fs;

          BinaryReader br;
          byte[] ImageData;

          fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

          br = new BinaryReader(fs);

          ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

          br.Close();
          fs.Close();

      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
          con.Open();
          if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
          {
        string q = "insert into recipes(Name,Image,Content)values('" + textBox_newRecipe.Text.ToString() + "','" + ImageData + "','" + content_box.Text.ToString() + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection made Successfuly..!");
                this.Close();

                myRecipes_Window obj_myRecipes_Window = new myRecipes_Window();
        obj_myRecipes_Window.Show();


//Retrieve Recipe Window:

public void FillRecipes()
{
            int column = 0;
            int row = 0;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM recipes";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

                if(column < 3)
                {
                    TextBlock nameTxt = new TextBlock();
                    nameTxt.Text = (dr["Name"].ToString());
                    nameTxt.FontSize = 20;
                    nameTxt.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            Grid.SetColumn(nameTxt, column);
                    Grid.SetRow(nameTxt, row);
            grid_Recipes.Children.Add(nameTxt);
            column++;
                }
        else
                {
                    column = 0;
                    row++;

                    TextBlock nameTxt = new TextBlock();
                    nameTxt.Text = (dr["Name"].ToString());
                    nameTxt.FontSize = 20;
                    nameTxt.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    Grid.SetColumn(nameTxt, column);
                    Grid.SetRow(nameTxt, row);
                    grid_Recipes.Children.Add(nameTxt);
                    column++;
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pelase post code as text, not images. If it is too much code, please provide a "Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example". A the very least, prodive a proper listing of the Table Structure. The SQL command used to create it is usually a good option. Also we need something mroe specific then "does not work". Show us the code you tried. Show us hte specific issue.

Comment: If it is not too large, store the image as encoded bitmap frame (e.g. PNG or JPEG) as a binary object. Then read it into a byte array, which is exposed as a view model property of type `byte[]`. Finally bind the Source property of an Image element in your view to that property.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes about my post. I'm sorry for the previous unclearness.